# rake spec runs test after specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rake

When I run `rake spec` in my Rails project it executes all specs and then tries to run tests (like `rake test`):

```
$ rake spec
ruby -S rspec ./spec/... #file list
# --> ...  normal RSpec output
Finished in 11.11 seconds
111 examples, 0 failures, 11 pending

# --> here starts the problem <--
Run options: 

# Running tests:

Finished tests in 0.000343s, 0.0000 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Do you know, why it tries to run `Test::Unit` tests even though I have none of them? (I don't even have `test/` directory)

**EDIT:**
When I run other `rake` commands, they do their job but then they finish with error, for example:

```
$ rake about
About your application's environment
Ruby version             1.9.3 (i686-linux)
RubyGems version         1.8.24
Rack version             1.4
Rails version            3.2.3
JavaScript Runtime       therubyracer (V8)
Action Pack version      3.2.3
Active Support version   3.2.3
Middleware               ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Lock, Rack::Runtime, Rack::MethodOverride, ActionDispatch::RequestId, Rails::Rack::Logger, ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions, ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions, ActionDispatch::RemoteIp, ActionDispatch::Reloader, ActionDispatch::Callbacks, ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, ActionDispatch::Flash, ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, ActionDispatch::Head, Rack::ConditionalGet, Rack::ETag, ActionDispatch::BestStandardsSupport
Application root         /path/to/project
Environment              development
path/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:167:in `block in non_options': file not found: about (ArgumentError)
        from path/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:146:in `map!'
        from path/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:146:in `non_options'
        from path/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:207:in `non_options'
        from path/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:52:in `process_args'
        from path/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:891:in `_run'
        from path/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:884:in `run'
        from path/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:21:in `run'
        from path/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:326:in `block (2 levels) in autorun'
        from path/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:27:in `run_once'
        from path/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:325:in `block in autorun'
```

Comment: What does your Rakefile look like? and maybe your Gemfile too.

Comment: Rakefile simply requires ````config/application```` and runs ````load_tasks````. There is nothing about the ````Test::Unit```` in the Gemfile, should I look for anything special?

Comment: I also have this issue. But if I run `rake notes` I don't see the problem. I think it is only related to tasks that have depends on `environment` task such as `task :about => [:environment]`, could you try with `rake notes`?

Comment: What did you do since you suddenly started experiencing this annoying behaviour?

Comment: I had those problems a while ago. After that I reisntalled my system (for other reasons) and now it's OK I think...

Comment: I have the same issue today, with RSpec 2.12.1.

Answer (score 3):

Any file with `require test/unit` enables an `at_exit` hook which attempts to run tests.

If any file loaded from your rake task does this, the at_exit hook tries to run the test using the last part of your rake command as the name of the test to run. In the case of `rake about`, it searches for a test named `about` which doesn't exist.

I had the problem when I had `shoulda` gem in my Gemfile. I solved it by including this in the Gemfile :

```
gem 'test-unit', :require => "test/unit"
```